# New lines in server generated report text field but not in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a table in `iReport` which generates to a PDF correctly:

```xml
<componentElement>
    <reportElement key="server vendor table" style="table" x="272" y="437" width="150" height="115"/>
    <jr:table>
        <jr:column width="50">
            <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="15" rowSpan="1">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Server Vendor]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </jr:columnHeader>
            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="18" rowSpan="1">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vendor}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
        </jr:column>
        <jr:column width="50">
            <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="15" rowSpan="1">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[# Hosts]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </jr:columnHeader>
            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="18" rowSpan="1">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
        </jr:column>
        <jr:column width="50">
            <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="15" rowSpan="1">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Host %]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </jr:columnHeader>
            <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="18" rowSpan="1">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="45" height="15"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
        </jr:column>
    </jr:table>
</componentElement>
```

When generating the report from `iReport`, the PDF is generated correctly, the result is:
[image: Correct result generated using iReport]

But when generated using Java the text entry for "HP" in the first column is split across multiple lines:
[image: Wrong result generated using Java code]

Note that only the "HP" text is split - longer text with a space in it (e.g. "Dell inc.") is *not* split.

I'm guessing that I need to set some properties, but I can't see figure out which property I need to set.

```java
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hardwaredata","???","???");       
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/reports/hardware_report.jrxml"));
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
input.close();
Map<String, Object> param_map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, param_map, conn);
String path = application.getRealPath("/") + "/"+"static_report.pdf";
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jPrint, path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before. I don't recall finding the true cause. Equally strangely (but happily) I found that strings like "HP " don't exhibit this behavior.

Try changing your text field to display this: `$F{Vendor} + " "`

Be sure to also log a bug! But that might be good enough to solve immediate problems.

Comment: Many thanks mdahlman! This solved the problem - a bit of a hack, but at least it's coming out correctly.

As suggested, I'll raise a bug against jasperreports!

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for the text that is aligning vertically check-mark the field titled "Stretch with overflow"

Comment: This doesn't work - the field isn't overflowing; there is plenty of width to fit the characters in.

Setting this value makes no difference to the "HP" string - but it can be seen to have an effect with some of the other entries (making them double-line) thus I did set it correctly.

Comment: Hmm that is extremely odd as to why it's doing that.